# ArrayFunction changing multiple cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a calculator and want to make a function to let the user know "Hey, don't use more than one checkbox in this column" (I don't wanna touch scripting as the last time I used it it broke a lot of things), and am using the ArrayFunction to allow me to make sure there is at least one checkbox in the column that is true.

```
=arrayformula(if(E4:E19=true,if(XOR(E4=true,xor(E5=true,xor(E6=true,xor(E7=true,xor(E8=true,xor(E9=true,xor(E10=true,xor(E11=true,xor(E12=true,xor(E13=true,xor(E14=true,xor(E15=true,xor(E16=true,xor(E17=true,xor(E18=true,E19=true))))))))))))))),"", "Too Many Gags!"),""))
```

When I have it trigger, however, it pops up in multiple cells, listing in whichever cells are checked. I want it to only appear in the cell below the checkboxes (in this case, E20).

I'm still fairly new to Google Sheets, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of exploring, I found a better alternative:

```
 =arrayformula(if(sum(N(E4:E19))>1, "Too Many Gags!",""))
```